# Expand on portrait mode, collapse on landscape mode using CSS only

Tags: ios, css, css-float, landscape-portrait

I have this code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="left">content left</div>
 <div class="right">content right</div>
</div>
```

My goal is to have both divs inside expand 100% to cover the whole width when the iphone is on portrait mode but collapse to 50% when on landscape mode so they both fit in the same line. This is my css:

```css
.wrapper {width:100%;height:auto;}

.left, .right {float:left;width:auto;}
```

It won't work. How do you do it?

Comment: You can use media query css for it. Check this link for detail `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries`

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate a little more please?

Comment: The problem is that the divs are either totally expanded on both modes or totally collapsed. I Only need them to expand on portrait mode so one comes below the other one occupying the whole width, whereas on landscape they should cover 50% each and align in the same line.

Comment: His link is broken and I would appreciate a little more information such an example. With media query you mean @media only screen whatever?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a media query for screen orientation. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation).

```css
/* assume portrait mode; everything set to the default */
.wrapper {width:100%;height:auto;}
.left, .right {width:auto;}

/* in landscape mode however, display left and right side by side */
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  .left, .right {float:left; width:50%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="left">content left</div>
 <div class="right">content right</div>
</div>
```